# Chrome 56 - Not Secure on Intranet

Tags: google-chrome

### The Brief

We've recently upgraded Chrome to v56. As of this release, Google has added a "not secure" warning to Chrome, to warn users that submitting usernames and passwords over HTTP is dangerous. Google has also said they will eventually show the same type of warning they already do for bad SSL.

---

### The Problem

We're now facing an issue where Chrome is displaying this behaviour on our intranet.
[image: Intranet Login]

---

### What we'd like to happen

We'd like to reconfigure Chrome to stop telling us about the login being insecure (it is, after all, on a private network, and doesn't rely on any external dependancies)

Is there any way to do this?

Moving forward, this could also be a problem when Google does implement the same type of warning they already do for bad SSL additionally.

Comment: Why not just spend a few bucks (or use LetsEncrypt) and get a certificate to encrypt your Intranet site?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Correct me if I'm wrong, but last I checked, CAs aren't allowed to issue certs to unresolvable intranet servers

Comment: "Correct me if I'm wrong," You're not wrong per se, but there's alternatives offered, ie:  https://www.globalsign.com/en/ssl/intranetssl/, and if you're using a non "local" FDQN for your network that's a subnet of a public domain name (ie: corp.mycompany.com, where mycompany.com is publically known) then you can use them (even if the server/subdomain is not Internet-reachable).  Alternatively you could setup a private certificate authority and create/issue self-signed certificates for use by the LAN clients.

Comment: Perhaps check out http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/103524/lets-encrypt-for-intranet-websites

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 interesting. I didn't know about IntranetSSL. I'll take a look

Comment: "Moving forward, this could also be a problem when Google does implement the same type of warning they already do for bad SSL additionally." - You do know you can bypass that warning right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> We'd like to reconfigure Chrome to stop telling us about the login
> being insecure (it is, after all, on a private network, and doesn't
> rely on any external dependancies)
>
> Is there any way to do this?

The correct and secure way to handle this problem, would be to create your ownSSL certificate with OpenSSL, and place your certificate into the operating system's certiifcate store.  You also would have to configure your intranet to only use HTTPS.

The insecure way, within Chrome 56+ go to `chrome://flags/#mark-non-secure-as`, and set the flag to **Always mark http as neurtral** instead of any of the other values:

- `Default`
- `Display a verbose state when password or credit card fields are detected on an HTTP page`
- `Always mark http as actively dangerous`

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a few months old but I had the same issue and found a better flags solution than disabling the warnings across the board. There is a flag that lets you list IP addresses to whitelist. For instance, I included http://192.168.0.1/. I'm not sure if it can use wildcards or do a whole 192.168.x.x range but you can list several different IP addresses.

Paste this in the address bar of Chrome:

```
chrome://flags/#unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure
```

Now enter the non SSL sites into the box, separated by commas.

Example:

[image]

Enable and hit "Relaunch".

FYI I'm using Chrome Version 84.0.4147.68 (Official Build) beta (64-bit).